# Every time I try to export a signed apk, ADT excludes a bunch of classes

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Lately, whenever I try to export a signed apk for my app using the Export Wizard in Eclipse, ADT is excluding a bunch of classes from the signed apk.

I can build and debug the app without any problems, and the *unsigned* apk has no problems running on my Android device, but if If I install the signed apk, the app immediately crashes after opening, giving me a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

I unzipped the apk and then used [dex2jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) to convert the classes.dex file into a jar file.

```
unzip my_app.apk
./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex
```

Examining the contents of the jar file (I used [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca)) revealed that it is, indeed, missing a bunch of classes. But why are they missing? Eclipse didn't give me any errors during the export... How can I create a signed apk that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I've got around the issue by avoiding the Export Wizard in Eclipse and manually signing/aligning instead ([instructions on android.com](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)).

Steps for those who don't like reading long instructions:

1. Export an unsigned apk (right-click on you project and select **Android Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package**)
2. Sign the application using jarsigner:

   > `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
   >   /path/to/same/keystore/used/by/export/wizard.keystore my_app.apk
   >   key_alias`

   (key_alias is the same alias prompted for by the Export Wizard)
3. Align the package:

   > zipalign -v 4 your_project_name-unaligned.apk
   >   your_project_name-aligned.apk

I'm still curious to know what's wrong with the Export Wizard and how I can get that working again.

Comment: This will work but you're now skipping the ProGuard step that the Export Wizard runs. Your APK is going to be much larger because of this. Highly recommend reading up on ProGuard and configuring it properly instead. That's an investment that will really pay off when writing Android apps.

Comment: Good to know. As it turns out, my new apk is only a few KB larger than the previous version of my app, so I'm not too worried about it yet. The thing I don't understand, though, is why did the export wizard work fine for months and then just start having problems with ProGuard now? My proguard-project.txt fine has NEVER had anything in it. What is the default ProGuard configuration that (apparently) has changed recently?

Comment: Did your code change? Or did you add dependencies on new libraries or namespaces? ProGuard guesses what classes you don't need or use and strips them from the JAR, so any changes to your project at all theoretically could cause this.

Comment: The weird thing is, according to the link in your answer (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html), ProGuard only runs if the "proguard.config" property is set (it isn't set for me), and *if* the "proguard.config" property is set, PG runs when building in release mode, and according to http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasecompile, release mode (and, therefore ProGuard) happens during my step #1 above. So PG *shouldn't* be running for me, and, if it does run, it should run during step #1 above. There appears to be something else wrong for me...

Answer (score 3):

When you export a signed application, the build system runs ProGuard. This will eliminate all classes, methods, and fields that ProGuard thinks are not being used. Take a look at your `proguard-project.txt` file for notes on how to modify the ProGuard settings to keep things that it might otherwise discard.

If you post details about the removed classes (specifically, how they are used in your code), we can provide specific guidance on what settings to change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not very familiar with ProGuard, but currently everything in proguard-project.txt is commented out.

Comment: Here's a good place to get started: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html. If everything is commented out, that just means ProGuard is running using its default configuration. You need to add some `-keep` flags to the file to configure ProGuard for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ProGuard? If so, try disabling it and exporting the signed app again.
Maybe your ProGuard config is broken.

Comment: I'm not using ProGuard (I don't think - project.properties has that line commented out).